# Passing Data into Forms Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

**Hypothetically;**

I have a simple system that has a list of choices on a screen. Each item has a button so you can add multiple supplementary items/information alongside the item selected but not change the item selected.
Each item has a unique id which I want to pass into the form so that the comment is always associated with the item.
I have a model that contains a foreign key that links the comment to the item and the Modelform works but I have to select the item from a drop down and I would like this information to be pre-populated in the form.
This seems so simple but I have been going round in circles for days.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

This is the Model for the 'comments'

```
    class roundscore(models.Model):
    scoreid = models.ForeignKey('Score', on_delete=CASCADE)
    shot_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shot_2 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shot_3 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shot_4 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shot_5 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shot_6 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    end_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    tens = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the form

```
    class AddRoundScore(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = roundscore
        fields = [
            'shot_1',
            'shot_2',
            'shot_3',
            'shot_4',
            'shot_5',
            'shot_6',
            'end_1',
            'tens',
            'scoreid'
        ]
```

This is the view

```
    def addscorecard (request, pk):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Score, pk=pk)
    post = Score.objects.values('id', 'rndname__roundname').filter(id = pk)
    print('Post', post)
    print('Request', type(post))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddRoundScore(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.scoreid = post
            post.save()
            print('Errors', form.errors.as_data())
            return redirect('readscorecard', post.pk)
    else:
        form = AddRoundScore()
        print('Errors', form.errors.as_data())
        return render(request, 'score/addscorecard.html', {'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'post': post})
```

The scoreid field links to a table where the score is recorded.
I have tried adding the pk to the function in order to pass it on to the score id rather than picking it out of a list when entering the shot values, this could lead to errors, picking the wrong scoreid.  I cannot use the name associated with the scoreid as this could be the same if the same round is attempted.
All I want to do is pre-populate the scoreid field with the value taken from the button on the scores page

```
<td><h5><a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" href="{% url 'score:addscorecard' post.id %}">Add Score</a></h5></td>
<td><h5><a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" href="{% url 'score:readscorecard' post.id %}">Read Score</a></h5></td>
```

For completeness here is the url file

```
     path("addscorecard/<int:pk>", views.addscorecard, name="addscorecard"),
```

I am sure the solution is quiet simple but I cannot get to the bottom of it

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I'd be happy to assist, but your description is bit confusing for me and you have not posted any code to make it clearer what you are doing. Please post you current relevant code and update your description so we can better understand what you want to do and what your issues are. Thank you.

Comment: Done.  I have added all the pertinent bits, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.
School boy error, the `scoreid` in the model should have been an integer field not a foreignkey field.
It is then to change the view `post.scoreid = post` to `post.scoreid = posts.id`
and it works